# Eclipse: An Error on a Curly Brace

Tags: java, syntax

This is a piece of code in my MainActivity all it does is clear text fields but I'm getting this error and its causing my program to not compile...its extremely frustrating as its the only lint error being shown...

}

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } //<---ERROR???????? syntax error on token "}", { expected
};
```

Comment: shouldn't `};` be `});`

Comment: I have tried }); also nothing seems to work and if I use { as lint expects then I get errors in my onClickListeners fields...

Comment: Ok got it I forgot to get new OnClickListener this fixed the formatting issue writing this line of code OnClickListener resetListener = new OnClickListener() {


    OnClickListener resetListener = new OnClickListener() { 
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  } 
 };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ok got it I forgot to get new OnClickListener this fixed the formatting issue writing this line of code OnClickListener resetListener = new OnClickListener() {


OnClickListener resetListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it saying `expected };`, that means you may be just missing the semi-colon.

Comment: why would you need a double semi-colon? I've written other onClickListeners within this Activity they were formatted exactly the same and I never got this error...one interesting thing I did find was when I imported my code to a text editor the curly brace in question looked like this }.  with what appears to be a period like character closely after it... any thoughts?